# how can i show google map API in asian language on android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any method to set the Google map API in asian language?

Answer (score 0):

Visit: http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63471

and also

Visit: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=1e00d71c8647012f&hl=en

Comment: is it for the web, can it apply to use in android ?

Comment: Sure you can embed a WebBrowser in your application and redirect to the maps website you need(obviously the more compact mobile version)